# What is the best algo for a table sorting problem?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

> We've been asked to design a system to manage tables at a restaurant.
> The core of this system is going to be a function called getTables
> which  takes in a party size and returns the optimal table(s) for this
> party.
>
> Our restaurant will have a fixed number of tables (you can make it up)
> and which seat 2,4 and 6 people. These tables can be combined to
> create bigger tables.  For instance, if you need to seat 7 people you
> can put together a 2-seat table and a 6-seat table to make an 8 seat
> table.

What type of algo is best suited for solution on this problem?
I was thinking of creating an initial Array to point the optimal seating configurations and then an algo that would receive the input of partySize and refer to the optimalSeating and sort accordingly. Has anyone appraoched a problem like this?

```
getCombos(availableTables) {
  optimalSeating = []; 
}


// Psuedo code
function getTables(partySize: number){. //7 (6,2) (4,4)

  let swapped = false;
  do {
    for (let i = 0; i < partySize.length; i++) {
      swapped = false;

      if(partySize[i] > remainingTables ){
        let curr = partySize[i];
        partySize[i] = partySize[i++];
        partySize[i+1] = curr;
        swapped = true
      } 
    }
  } (while)

  
  return; //Returns optimal table(s) for this partySize
}
```

I ended up approaching with what ended up basically being Bubble Sort but that doesn't quite work given the variances on different table sizes and optimal solutions.

Comment: What does the `partySize` have ? Is it an array of groups of people? Where is the number of tables of each size?

Comment: Is there any notion of time in this problem?  In real restaurants, arrivals and departures are staggered and unpredictable.  And often the problem has several competing criteria:  You don't want to crowd parties together when the restaurant is not busy.  But you want to have adjacent free tables to combine for a large party.  If waitstaff members are responsible for a region, you want to distribute parties equitably among them.  So are you just working on a static list of parties and a fixed set of tables?  Or do you have to consider these other questions?

Comment: @PhenomenalOne it's an array of groups you can see in the comment there 
```// (6,2 or (4,4)```
That would represent an example parameter for `partySize`

Comment: @ScottSauyet no not needed! good questions for sure, but essentially pretend that the it's a computer that tells the hostess which tables to push together as various party sizes arrive.

Comment: I'm afraid this is still significantly underspecified.  It's not clear what you mean by "optimal" here.  What are you optimizing for?

Comment: Sure, optimal would be using the appropriate table size (or combo of tables) for the requested party size. 
Example – if you have a group of 4 it would be best to assign a 4 seat table opposed to pushing two 2 seat tables together. 
Another example – It would be least optimal if you had a group of 8 it would be least optimal to provide two 6 seat tables as you'd be losing 4 potential seats to satisfy that 8 person party